# is there another set $S⊆N$ for wich: $(\forall n \in S):\;a \equiv b\mod(n)\implies a=b \;?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Based on the previous post:[$a \equiv b$ $mod(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} $ implies $a=b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3413131/a-equiv-b-modn-for-all-n-in-mathbbn-implies-a-b/3413146#3413146)

It's true that $$(\forall n \in \Bbb N):\;a \equiv b\mod(n)\implies a=b  $$

The new question is: are there another sets $S⊆\Bbb N, S \neq \Bbb N$ for wich: $$(\forall n \in S):\;a \equiv b\mod(n)\implies a=b  \;?$$

Comment: What is your convention? is $0 \in \mathbb N$?

Answer (score 2):

**Claim** $S$ is such a set if and only if $S$ is infinite.

**Proof** $\Rightarrow$. Let $a,b$ be so that 
$$(\forall n \in S):\;a \equiv b\mod(n)$$

Assume by condtradiction that $a \neq b$. Then $|b-a|>0$.  Since $S$ is infinite, there exists some $n \in S$ such that $n> |b-a|$. But then
$$a \equiv b \pmod{n}$$
implies that $b-a =kn $for some integer. Since $b \neq a$ we have $|k| >0$ and since $n> |b-a|$ we have $k <1$ contradictions.

$\Leftarrow$. Assume by contradiction that $S$ is finite. Note here that $\pmod{0}$ arithmetic makes no sense, so I assume that $0 \notin \mathbb N$.

Let $N$ be the product of elements of $S$. Then 
$$a \equiv a+N \pmod{n} \forall n \in S$$
and hence $a =a+N$ which implies that $N=0$, a contradiction.

**P.S.** If you want to include modulo zero arithemtic in your computations, and understand that $a \equiv b \pmod{0}$ means $a=b$, then the claim is that $S$ works if and only if either $S$ is infinite or $ 0\in S$.